# CodeIgniter: How to calculate, store and show final score to the user?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

New to PHP and CodeIgniter framework.

I have a single question in the `database` and i can save the answer properly. But i'm struggling to save the answer to the allocated `user_id` and output the `score` to the `user` in the end of the test.

If answer is correct, it will show `1/1` else `0/1`. Can someone please assist me?

** From table `user_login` only `id` is needed, table `results` is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCi83.png) and table `exercises` is [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYRlC.png).

This is my `Controller`:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Exercise');
}

function exercise_demo() {
    //get the exercise out of the database to give to
    //the view so that it can be shown.
    $this->load->model('Exercise');

    //give this to the view in an array
    $data = array();
    $data['exercise'] = $this->Exercise->load_exercise('Geography', '2');

    $this->load->view('exercise_demo', $data);
}

function storedemo() {       

    $answer = $this->input->post('answer');

    $id = $this->input->post('exerciseid');

    $this->load->model('Exercise');

    $correct = $this->Exercise->check_answer($id, $answer);

    //store this in a database table
    $data = array(
        'answer_given' => $this->input->post('answer'),
        'exercise_id' => $this->input->post('exerciseid'),
        'result_tf' => $correct,
        'user_id' => '0'
    );

    //transfer data to model
    $this->Exercise->insert_result($data);

}  }
```

This is my `Model`:

```
class Exercise extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function load_exercise($topic, $difficulty) {

    return $this->db->get_where('exercises', array('topic' => $topic, 'difficulty' => $difficulty))->row();
}

function insert_result($data) {
    $this->db->insert('results', $data);

    $is_inserted = $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
    if ($is_inserted) {
        echo 'Answer saved!';
    } else {
        echo 'Something went wrong. No insert ):';
    }
}

public function check_answer($id, $answer) {

    //get the exercise out of the db
    $exercise = $this->db->get_where('exercises', array('id' => $id))->row();

    return $exercise->solution == $answer ? '1' : '0';
}
}
```

This is my View `exercise_demo`:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" action="<?= base_url('index.php/home/storedemo') ?>" >
        <div id ="exercise">

            <?= $exercise->exercise ?>

        </div>

        <input type ="hidden" name ="exerciseid" value="<?= $exercise->id ?>">

        <input type="submit">

        <br />
        <br />
        <h3> SCORE: </h3>
        <div id="result">
            <h3><?= $result ?> / 1 </h3> (comment this out to work properly)
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the question (stackoverflow question that is). Is insert_result where the problem is happening? What behavior are you currently getting? Could you show us the columns of the database tables we're talking about?

Comment: please only post the relevant code, try to simplify your example in a way it reflects on the problem only. No one will be reading through ton's of code! Check here: [**asking your own questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Goose , It only allows me 2 pictures because as i haven't got 10 reputation. I re-uploaded the pictures **above** as there was an error showing them. I'm trying, firstly, to show the score to the user after he submits all answers. I only have one question though. And yes it uses `insert_result` and shows only 'Yay! It works!'. `check_answer` in the `Model` is a way to check answers but i don't know how to use it. Apologies. I edited most of code @Vickel

Comment: @Goose , i use tinyint on result_tf to save the answer there. I don't know if that helps. If anything, let me know i'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: if you are just now learning PHP, you should be staying away from ALL of the frameworks for at least a year

Comment: @tereško, welp, tell that to my supervisor.

Comment: @Goose, Ahh silly mistake - thanks it saves the answer!! However, it opens a new page called `storedemo` and use "echo" to say "Answer saved!". But how can i show `answer_tf` at `storedemo`? `storedemo` is a function in the Controller.

Comment: I don't understand you're question. Feel free to post a new full question for that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work from start to end.

function `storedemo` gets the posted answer

It sends it to `check_answer` to find if it's correct or not.

`check_answer` returns the string 'correct' if true and 'incorrect' if false.

`storedemo` then uses `insert_result` to place the return of `check_answer` into the database column `result_tf`

`result_tf` is a tiny int. You're trying to pass a string into an int column. This is most definitely not going to work.

Have `check_answer` return the ints 1 or 0 instead of the strings 'correct' or 'incorrect' and that will allow you to insert that into `result_tf`

If your code still isn't giving expected results, it's because there are other problems. If so, debug it yourself a little longer now that you're a little closer, if you're still absolutely lost after a while, I'd recommend you post a new question.